# Trying to make an apk file online with Python/Kivy, but it does not work. Why?

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy, internal-server-error

I'm trying to learn to program in `Python2.7/Kivy` and build applications for Android platform.

So I uploaded a zip-file containing a `main.py` and a `kv` file to http://android.kivy.org, but as I push the `submit` button I get:

> 500 Internal Server Error

I couldn't find any other questions dealing with this problem. What am I doing wrong? The program runs perfectly fine under Windows 7 and I filled the textboxes on the site correctly (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to use it for a week now, but it keeps giving me this error. Any alternative methods to make an apk file under Win7?

Comment: This tool isn't really maintained, we should probably take it offline entirely. The main option for building on windows is to use a linux virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's 500 internal server error, it's most probably from the server side not your fault.
May be should try later.